# Navigating simple, yet large set of data

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have got a approximately 12GB of tab-separated data in a very simple format:

```
mainIdentifier, altIdentifierType, altIdentifierText
```

MainIdentifier is not a unique row identifier - only the whole combination of the 3 columns is unique. My main use-case is looking up corresponding entries going from `mainIdentifier` or going from two different types of alternative identifiers.

From what I can glean, I would need to construct a lookup index for each entry direction to make it fast. However, given the simplicity of the task, I do not really need the index pointing to the record - the index itself is the answer.

I've tried sqlite3 in python but as expected, the result is not as fast as I would've liked. I am now considering just storing the two lists and moving around in a binary-search fashion, however, I do not want to re-invent the wheel - is there any way existing solution how to solve this?

Also, I intend to run this a REST-enabled service, so it's not feasible for the lookup table to be stored in memory in any fashion..

Comment: Check out memcached. It scales to large datasets (if you don't mind throwing a lot of RAM and/or servers at the problem) and can be addressed by many processes.

Comment: I think that for a foreseeable future, it's going to be a small internal tool used by only a handful of users - so scaling is not an issue. I would also like to keep it simple internally, as we are releasing command-line versions of the tools as well

Comment: What is not as fast as you liked? What query on what table with what indexes?

Comment: I've created a SQLite table and inserted the data. Then, I am doing a simple query restricting on mainIdentifier - it takes around 20-30s to find a result (and that's on quarter of the data to try out)